# I am trying to create a new column in python dataframe using apply, lambda and if elif else functions. I am getting the error of invalid syntex

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

This is the code I used.

```
B2B.FY= B2B.Date.apply(lambda x: '2017-18' if x>='2017-07-01' and x=<'2018-03-31' else ('2018-19' if x>='2018-04-01' and x=<'2019-03-31' else ('2019-20' if x>='2019-04-01' and x=<'2020-03-31' else ('2020-21' if x>='2020-07-01' and x=<'2021-03-31' else ('2021-22' if x>='2021-04-01' and x=<'2022-03-31' else '2022-23')))))



this is the sample of date column.
0       2017-07-07
1       2017-07-14
2       2017-07-14
3       2017-07-14
4       2017-07-25
5       2017-07-25
6       2017-07-31
7       2017-07-14
8       2017-07-25
9       2017-07-21
10      2017-07-12
11      2017-07-25
12      2017-07-31
13      2017-07-15
14      2017-07-15
15      2017-07-18
16      2017-07-18
17      2017-07-18
18      2017-07-18
19      2017-07-18
20      2017-07-18
21      2017-07-18
```

and this is the error I am getting.

File "C:\Users\Optimus\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9712/3702499445.py", line 1
B2B.FY= B2B.Date.apply(lambda x: '2017-18' if x>='2017-07-01' and x=<'2018-03-31' else ('2018-19' if x>='2018-04-01' and x=<'2019-03-31' else ('2019-20' if x>='2019-04-01' and x=<'2020-03-31' else ('2020-21' if x>='2020-07-01' and x=<'2021-03-31' else ('2021-22' if x>='2021-04-01' and x=<'2022-03-31' else '2022-23')))))

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to improve:

- From what [OneCricketeer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73975918/i-am-trying-to-create-a-new-column-in-python-dataframe-using-apply-lambda-and-i#comment130617375_73975918)

> `=<` is not a valid operator.

So one will have to use `<=`.

- Apart from that, in order to create a new column named `FY`, as Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name, instead of `B2B.FY` use `B2B['FY']`.

With all the changes in place, the following will should do the work

```
B2B['FY'] = B2B['Date'].apply(lambda x: '2017-18' if x>='2017-07-01' and x<='2018-03-31' else ('2018-19' if x>='2018-04-01' and x<='2019-03-31' else ('2019-20' if x>='2019-04-01' and x<='2020-03-31' else ('2020-21' if x>='2020-07-01' and x<='2021-03-31' else ('2021-22' if x>='2021-04-01' and x<='2022-03-31' else '2022-23')))))

[Out]:
          Date       FY
0   2017-07-07  2017-18
1   2017-07-14  2017-18
2   2017-07-14  2017-18
3   2017-07-14  2017-18
4   2017-07-25  2017-18
5   2017-07-25  2017-18
6   2017-07-31  2017-18
7   2017-07-14  2017-18
8   2017-07-25  2017-18
9   2017-07-21  2017-18
10  2017-07-12  2017-18
11  2017-07-25  2017-18
12  2017-07-31  2017-18
13  2017-07-15  2017-18
14  2017-07-15  2017-18
15  2017-07-18  2017-18
16  2017-07-18  2017-18
17  2017-07-18  2017-18
18  2017-07-18  2017-18
19  2017-07-18  2017-18
20  2017-07-18  2017-18
21  2017-07-18  2017-18
```

---

**Notes:**

- Make sure that the column `Date` is not of datetime, else one will get a

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'